# How do I control audio volume in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a volume slider for my application.  I don't mind whether it controls master volume or program volume, but I don't want to use pinvoke if there's an alternative.  I'm using C# with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Changing Master Volume Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294292) question, there are 2 different APIs, depending on your OS (Xp or Vista).

Still, if you can call from your .net program some of the winapi functions mentionned in that question, you should be able to implement what you are asking for.