# Is there a way in Java (+- JNA) to set the master system volume reliably in XP+Vista+Windows 7?

Tags: java, audio

Appears that java's sound API's work well for single streams, and even for setting the input from the microphone, but not for setting the master volume level in Vista/Windows 7.

refs:

[Java Sound API to access the system/master volume control in Vista and Win 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727511/java-sound-api-to-access-the-system-master-volume-control-in-vista-and-win-7)

[How to adjust speaker volume from Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734808/how-to-adjust-speaker-volume-from-java-program)

[Changing master volume level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294292/changing-master-volume-level/294525#294525)
 only works on XP for the master volume

Anybody have something that'll work for all of them (without compatibility mode or controlling the mouse to increase volume level [robot-like]).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964947/set-computer-volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seeing as there appears to be no native solution, my current method is to use jna to send keyboard strokes for "keyboard volume up and down":

https://superuser.com/questions/82229/how-to-control-master-volume-in-windows-7/86227#86227

You might be able to create a dll then hook into it that is "vista volume aware" and could actually control it right, and call methods on that, using jna.

ffi/jna/jnr/jacob (to access IAudioEndpointVolume etc.) might work. (appears jna doesn't really support COM?)  ffi looks scary too, in that regard.

Could possibly use a java [COM bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3547587/32453) to do the same.  So next thought is to try either [bridj](https://code.google.com/p/bridj/wiki/COM#Example) or jacob

Answer (score 1):

Have done my share of JNI and steer clear where I can. As long as you have to go native to accomplish something, and assuming the task is simple and performance isn't a major issue, I've found it a lot easier to launch a separate process than deal with JNI or any of its cousins. Here is some C++ code adapted from [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/03/06/how-do-i-change-the-master-volume-in-windows-vista.aspx) article that will set the master volume based on a single command line parameter:

```
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h> 

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{
double newVolume = _ttof(lpCmdLine);

CoInitialize(NULL);

IMMDeviceEnumerator* deviceEnumerator = NULL;
if(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (LPVOID *)&deviceEnumerator) == S_OK) {
    IMMDevice* defaultDevice = NULL;
    if(deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &defaultDevice) == S_OK) {
        IAudioEndpointVolume* endpointVolume = NULL;
        if(defaultDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, (LPVOID *)&endpointVolume) == S_OK) {
            endpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar((float)newVolume, NULL);
            endpointVolume->Release();
        }
        defaultDevice->Release();
    }
    deviceEnumerator->Release();
}

CoUninitialize();

return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056089/32453 if looking for something to call out to.

Comment: @rogerdpack isnt this a noop for XP?

Comment: @SarahManning appears to be vista+ yes