# Using IAudioEndpointVolume

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am new to c++ but i was wondering how i could use the IAudioEndpointVolume interface to get system volume information.  I don't know what i need to include and use. Ive already looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964574.aspx but it didn't help because i don't know enough about c++, the reason i am doing this is actually for a java native interface project in java. I'm using Windows 7. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IAudioEndpointVolume is a COM interface, which you obviously can use from C++ but it's not restricted to C++.

Before mucking about with JNI (especially if you haven't got much experience in C or C++) I'd be tempted to look for a Java/COM Bridge. You might be able to find some information here: [How to choose a Java-COM bridge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547587/how-to-choose-a-java-com-bridge)

Comment: but i would still prefer to do it in c++

Comment: You'll need to gather some basic COM programming knowledge then. There's more info about the interface and which header file to include here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679138.aspx

Comment: is their any other way to play wth the volume in c++