# Output shows up in console, but disappears when redirected to file

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm using a tool that tests hard disks, fstest.exe. It runs fine from the command line, displaying how long it took to do various file-creation/-deletion/-mangling tasks. The usual output, when run from the command line as `fstest.exe otherParams`, looks like this:

```
---
CPU Usage: 0.0%
Disk reads/sec: 0
Disk writes/sec: 0
Disk bytes/read: 0
Disk bytes/write: 0
Test duration: 0 milliseconds, 1153 ticks (3507177 ticks/sec)
---
```

The trouble is that when I redirect the output to file, it doesn't display anything:

`fstest.exe otherParams > out.txt` creates an empty out.txt file, even though the command otherwise executed just fine (and created a few test-files as part of its execution).

**How can I force this application to redirect output to a file?** I've tried looking at it more closely with PowerShell (via Start-Process), and both the standard-out and standard-error streams are just empty.

Other things I've tried:

```
cmd /c "fstest.exe otherParams > out.txt"

fstest.exe otherParams 2>&1 >> out.txt

fstest.exe otherParams | sort

powershell Start-Process -FilePath .\fstest.exe -ArgumentList @("create2", "-openexisting") -RedirectStandardOutput out.txt -RedirectStandardError err.txt -wait
```

(That creates both out.txt and err.txt, both empty.)

What would cause an application to change its output depending on whether it's redirected, and is there any way I can make it redirect to file?

UPDATE: I've gotten my hands on the source code. It's C++, and the output is just straightforward `printf` statements.

Comment: Is your program exiting normally (through a return)? Or are you interrupting it with a signal interrupt? It could be that the buffer doesn't get flushed or whatever if it exits that way.

Comment: @Gray it's always exiting normally (via returning, and exit code is 0), but for some reason it wouldn't flush the buffer when redirecting to file -- only when printing to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the program in question wasn't flushing stdout after doing a `printf` to it. Apparently, cmd is willing to flush that buffer when printing to the console, but not when redirecting output to a file. (Or perhaps the file handle is closed before the console could force a flush.) The program was exiting normally (via return, exit code always 0).

To answer the question: I had to fix the program; there was nothing I could do with command-line switches or redirects to change it.

Comment: Ha! I was right... I should have just posted it as an answer. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Interesting.   I would have thought that program termination would have flushed any IO buffers associated with the process..

Comment: @Gray it wasn't exiting abnormally, as near as I can make out. Exit code was always 0, and perusing the source code (admittedly, without a debugger) made it look like it was exiting normally.

Answer (score 2):

`CMD` can handle [up to 10 file descriptors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). Try redirecting them to separate files to identify the descriptor your program writes to:

```
fstest.exe {params} 0>out0.txt 3>out3.txt 4>out4.txt 5>out5.txt ...
```

Comment: That closed the cmd window, and out4.txt had the command prompt in it, but all others were empty.

Answer (score 1):

If it's writing to standard error, instead of standard output, redirect thusly:

```
fstest.exe otherParams 2> out.txt
```

Comment: Alas, no luck. I've tried redirecting both streams to the file.

Comment: @PaulMarshall    When you get this figured out, post it--I'm really curious, now.