# output from corFlags.exe and dumpbin.exe disappear when redirected

Tags: powershell, windows-7

We are trying to automate some procedures using corFlags.exe and dumpbin.exe.  Trying to capture the output from either of these programs has been impossible so far.  In detail, executing

```
corFlags.exe yourfavorite.dll
```

in cmd.exe or in powershell.exe (with appropriate change of syntax) produces output just fine, but as soon as one attempts to capture the output, either through re-direction or piping, e.g.

```
corflags.exe yourFavorite.dll >>out.txt
```

or

```
$l_result = &corflags yourFavorite.dll | select-string -pattern "32BIT"
```

and the output of corflags is lost.  There is a similar problem with dumpbin.

This is occuring on a Windows 7 sp1 machine (6.1.7601 sp1 build 7601).

I am guessing they suffer from the flaw of not flushing their output streams before exiting. See [Output shows up in console, but disappears when redirected to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561381/output-shows-up-in-console-but-disappears-when-redirected-to-file) for example.

We have found no way of working around this problem so far (executing in sub-process/batch process/etc. etc.)  Does anyone know of a work-around to this problem?  Thanks.

A nice, simple demonstration of the problem is as follows.  Open the PowerShell ISE and try to run "corFlags.exe some.dll" within the console window.  You will not be able to get any output from it!

Comment: If you write your own application that uses `Process.Start` (or similar) to run `corflags`, and attempt to flush the standard output stream manually somehow, or attempt to set the standard output buffer size to something very small, could that work? Also, could you verify somehow that `corflags` doesn't actually stop producing output when stdout is redirected (as some applications do)?

Comment: Thanks bzlm for the reply. I am not sure that would work: as soon as execution returns from running corflags, the output is lost, I think, though I'm not at all sure.  And it really seems to be a hack to write an application just to run another application....

Comment: This seems to be fixed in both WMF 5.1 and PowerShell 6 (on the off chance that anyone is still following this).