# Can I control something like volume mixer using Java?

Tags: java, audio, volume, mixer

I'm trying to make an app where I can (on the fly) control volume mixer without having to open it up.
With this app, I would be able to control different application volumes using macros, or even create a physical device.
I did a search, but I havent found a way using Java.
What kind of libraries do I need and is there certain functions I should be looking at?

EDIT: Windows Volume Mixer

Comment: Could you give more details? What volume mixer? At the current stage your question is closeable for: *"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"*.

Comment: Windows Volume Mixer, Apologies

Comment: [Java Sound API to access the system/master volume control in Vista and Win 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727511/java-sound-api-to-access-the-system-master-volume-control-in-vista-and-win-7)

Comment: [Set Computer Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964947/set-computer-volume)