# How to adjust microphone input level in delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, windows-xp, audio, microphone

i want to Get/Set the mic level using delphi? that works on vista and xp uses only mmsystem, any freeware component will do as long as no external dll's on the run.

and also getting the peak level.

Comment: Looks like you've asked this question twice, XBasic3000: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437050/how-to-adjust-master-volume-in-vista-xp .  Can you delete this duplicate please?

Comment: sorry but that for the Master Volume. and this is for the Microphone volume sorry if it looks the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the Freeware component.. http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-packages/waveaudio/ it doesnot use any external component.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried, but [there](http://delphiheaven.blogspot.com/2007/03/set-volume-for-microphone-mute-it.html) has been described by Vladimir M. Todorov.

Comment: Full source code here: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1204
I dont know Vista but it works on Windows 7