# Mute/unmute, Change master volume in Windows 7 x64 with C#

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-7-x64

How can I adjust master volume in Windows 7 with C#?

I have seen an excellent implementation using winmm.dll [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/Windows-Mixer-Control-in-C.htm), but it works with XP and not with Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046715/285594

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeProject has a very good sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx). Note that it relies on COM interop completely (check COM interface like [IAudioEndpointVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370892%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [IAudioMeterInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368227%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN if you are interested in implementation details), and works ONLY for Vista/Win7 and higher.

> Minimum supported client: Windows Vista
>
> Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2008

Comment: Excellent, I tested it and it worked in Windows 7 x64. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The codeproject article has been removed :(
Anyone out there who can insert the code here?

Comment: This answer contains some code (probably not the one from removed codeproject article, but at least it contains essential COM interfaces & definitions): http://stackoverflow.com/a/14322736/356716

Answer (score 12):

I used the nuget package Naudio successfully with this code:

```
public void SetVolume(int level)
   {
            try
            {
                //Instantiate an Enumerator to find audio devices
                    NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
                        //Get all the devices, no matter what condition or status
                NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceCollection DevCol = MMDE.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.All);
                //Loop through all devices
                foreach (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice dev in DevCol)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (dev.State == NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.Active)
                        {
                            var newVolume = (float)Math.Max(Math.Min(level, 100),0) / (float)100;

                            //Set at maximum volume
                            dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = newVolume;

                            dev.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = level == 0;

                            //Get its audio volume
                            _log.Info("Volume of " + dev.FriendlyName + " is " + dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Debug("Ignoring device " + dev.FriendlyName + " with state " + dev.State);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Do something with exception when an audio endpoint could not be muted
                        _log.Warn(dev.FriendlyName + " could not be muted with error " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //When something happend that prevent us to iterate through the devices
                _log.Warn("Could not enumerate devices due to an excepion: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```