# Mute microphone on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have an problem with muting the mic on an windows 7 machine. But all the code i have found dosen't run ore it's not doing anything the runned. Have is it done for an Windows 7 machine using C# code. I just need an on/off solution.
The DDL file works also with Win x64bit. But i thing that i creates an error another place.

```
        mixers.Recording.Lines.GetMixerFirstLineByComponentType(
                     MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE.SRC_MICROPHONE).Volume = 0;
            if (!mediaElement1.CheckAccess()) mediaElement1.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate { mediaElement1.Play(); });


            if (MessageBox.Show("Incoming Call from: " + string.Format(e.RemoteParticipant), "Video Chat Call", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                mixers.Recording.Lines.GetMixerFirstLineByComponentType(
                             MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE.SRC_MICROPHONE).Volume = 1;
                if (!mediaElement1.CheckAccess()) mediaElement1.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate { mediaElement1.Stop(); });
                _currentConversation.StartVideo();

            }'
```

If error occurs at `if (MessageBox.Show("Incoming Call from: " + string.Format(e.RemoteParticipant), "Video Chat Call", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)` and says {"Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."}

Comment: What is `e.RemoteParticipant`? if you put that string.Format on it's own line and saved it to a variable does the error happen on that line instead? In fact I don't see a overload of `string.Format` that only takes one parameter, is that a extension method?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046715/285594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.computercabal.com/2010/11/mute-microphone-from-c-on-windows.html -- this gentleman appears to have had a similar problem, and he's provided the source code for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Audio Switcher Api
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/4.0.0-alpha5

Code is quite simple:

```
private async void btnMute_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var audioController = new CoreAudioController();
    var devices = await audioController.GetDevicesAsync(DeviceType.Capture, DeviceState.Active);
    var device = devices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDefaultDevice);
    if(device != null) {
        await device.SetMuteAsync(!device.IsMuted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Looks like `SetMuteAsync` should be `MuteAsync` though, or you can just use `ToggleMute`

Answer (score 0):

this might help: [Windows Mixer Control in C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/)

Good luck :).

EDIT: It can also mute certain devices if I'm right.

Comment: Seems to greate this error for me Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. :(