# program that records audio: mute microphone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio, microphone

I recently began coding a C# program that does simple audio recording via a microphone connected to a PC (i.e. laptop microphone, desktop headset, etc etc...).

So now, I've got everything done like recording, pausing, stopping, saving, and replaying, but I can't seem to code the last feature: muting the microphone. This means that the program continues to record audio, but the recorded data is silence because the microphone is muted and there is no input from the microphone.

I've done some searching and all I found is actually disabling the hardware itself in order to mute it, rather than just cutting input from the microphone hardware.

Can anyone here show me how to stop receiving input from the microphone in C#? And then, restore back to receiving input when selected to do so?

EDIT: I should also say that I'm using winmm.dll as an dll import, like this:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll",EntryPoint="mciSendStringA", ExactSpelling=true,
            CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int record(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString,
                                 int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mute microphone on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821969/mute-microphone-on-windows-7)

Comment: I don't understand the solution, it has a source code and a .dll library to import(?). How do I go around implementing it? Is the solution the .dll library? Or must I also refer to the source code too? (Take it as there is no mute feature yet in the C# program)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "restore back to receiving input" possibly with the same level settings, it is probably a good idea to not touch the microphine levels and muting setting at all but simply set the incoming samples to zero for the "muted" time interval.

Otherwise you should interact with the [Mixer as shown here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/sound/article.php/c10931/Windows-Mixer-Control-in-C.htm)

Comment: Ah, so I how do I go about setting the incoming samples to zero?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question! Sorry for the mess!

Comment: If your code records audio, you'll have an array of shorts before you save this to disk. Simply set all these shorts to zero.

Comment: I do not understand this array of shorts. I know shorts is like a data type? (Int, String, double?) But to better clarify things I should state that I'm using the winmm.dll file via DllImport, like this:
`[DllImport("winmm.dll",EntryPoint="mciSendStringA", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError=true)]`


`private static extern int record(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);`

Comment: Well, this function is a high level function, which does several steps. Use some lower level function to get access to the actual samples read in.