# Mute system from code

Tags: c#, audio, windows-7, pinvoke, volume

I'm trying to mute the PC speaker from my C# console application. I've tried the code suggested [on this site](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial176_Get-and-set-the-wave-sound-volume.html) and it doesn't affect the volume on my machine. I need the code to work on Win7 and I assume that code only works on XP. I also tried this:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr uDeviceID, int dwVolume);

waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

But when the waveOutSetVolume method is called, the system is not muted and no error are thrown. Is there a way to mute the PC from C# in Win7?

Comment: do you want it for your application only or for the entire system to be muted?

Comment: Windows API calls don't throw exceptions. Try checking Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

Comment: @JohnRiselvato - Entire system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control) is what you are looking for. this has been test with windows 7 and also this question as been asked on SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986007/mute-unmute-change-master-volume-in-windows-7-x64-with-c-sharp). Which probably will help you get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the DLL is too bloated for my needs and the source is quite complicated so I'm going to try and pick it apart first as I just need the volume aspect.

Comment: I guess this is what you are going with?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't condense it so I just used the library as-is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio` extension for the [AudioSwitcher](https://github.com/xenolightning/AudioSwitcher) library. Just install it as a Nuget package using Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio`

It has a methods like `Mute`, `ToggleMute` and the `Volume` property, so you can set the value you want.

Here is an example:

```
using (var audio = new CoreAudioController())
{
    audio.DefaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mute the PC speaker.  It is a basic device, has no mixer, etc.  What comes out of it is a constant volume.

What you show in your example is code to control your sound card's mixer, which is a completely different device.

Comment: The example John Reselvato posted works on my machine and I guess that it controls the sound card mixer. That's what I'd like to achieve (although the sample posted is very bloated and somewhat complicated to dissect just the volume part).

Comment: @SSL, Oh, I thought you wanted to control the PC Speaker.  Yes, the winmm API has quite a bit to it.