# How to update Slider value automatically C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, wpf-controls, auto-update

I have made an app to controll the volume of my pc it is setting the slider's value to the volume of the pc when i am starting the app but i want it to update it's value if i change the volume using the keys or the windows volume controller.

```
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;

namespace Launcher
{ 
    public partial class Media : Window
    {
        public Media()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var deviceEnumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var device = deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
            Vols.Value = device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar;
            vol.Content = Math.Round((float)Vols.Value, 2) * 100;
        }
        private void vols_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            vol.Content = Math.Round((float)Vols.Value, 2) * 100;
        }

        private void VolSlider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            var deviceEnumerator = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var device = deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
            device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar= (float)Vols.Value;
            vol.Content = Math.Round((float)Vols.Value, 2) * 100;
        }
    }
}
```

It basically changes the volume of my pc if i change the slider value and shows the volume in an label, and i want those values to be updated when the pc volume is modified.

Comment: You need to bind the value of the volume to a the slider using Data Binding and the model-view-viewmodel design pattern

Comment: how can i do that? I've never done binding between system elements and ui elements

Comment: You can listen OnVolumeNotification event. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972775

Comment: @DanielMan it's hard to explain in a stackoverflow answer... Go to WPF documentation and start from the base with model-view-viewmodel