# How to set volume in C# and Windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, volume

I want to set system volume to 65% in winforms. Is there any dll which I can import and use it?

I tried

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
    private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDecVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
        (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
    }

    private void btnIncVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
        (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }

    static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveOutSetVolume")]
        public static extern int WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);
    }
}
```

But in this I can increase or decrease not able to set a perfect value. My question can be possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986007/mute-unmute-change-master-volume-in-windows-7-x64-with-c-sharp) but answer of question is no more supported because supported link is deleted and other supported link just give detailed tutorial which in itself a great study.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mute/unmute, Change master volume in Windows 7 x64 with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986007/mute-unmute-change-master-volume-in-windows-7-x64-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var v = AudioMixerHelper.GetVolume(0x2, 0x4);

            AudioMixerHelper.SetVolume(0x2, 0x4, 140);
        }
    }




    class AudioMixerHelper
    {
       // This is the only error code we will use
        public const int MMSYSERR_NOERROR = 0;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        public const int MAXPNAMELEN = 32;

        public const int MIXER_SHORT_NAME_CHARS = 16;
        public const int MIXER_LONG_NAME_CHARS = 64;

        public const int MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE = 2;
        public const int MIXER_GETLINEINFOF_COMPONENTTYPE = 3;

        public const int MIXER_GETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE = 0;
        public const int MIXER_SETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE = 0;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CT_CLASS_SWITCH = 0x20000000;
        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CT_CLASS_FADER = 0x50000000;

        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CT_UNITS_BOOLEAN = 0x10000;
        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CT_UNITS_UNSIGNED = 0x30000;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_FADER =
            (MIXERCONTROL_CT_CLASS_FADER | MIXERCONTROL_CT_UNITS_UNSIGNED);

        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_VOLUME =
            (MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_FADER + 1);

        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_BOOLEAN =
            (MIXERCONTROL_CT_CLASS_SWITCH | MIXERCONTROL_CT_UNITS_BOOLEAN);

        public const int MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_MUTE =
            (MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_BOOLEAN + 2);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // SRC COMPONENT TYPE
        public const int MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_SRC_FIRST = 0x1000;

        public const int MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_SRC_LINE =
            (MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_SRC_FIRST + 2);

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // DST COMPONENT TYPE
        public const int MIXERLINE_COMPONENTTYPE_DST_SPEAKERS = 4;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // This is the callback notification which we use for synchronization
        public const int MM_MIXM_CONTROL_CHANGE = 0x3D1;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        // This is the parameter used to enable .._CONTROL_CHANGE notifications
        public const int CALLBACK_WINDOW = 0x10000;

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]                                                    // mixerOpen
        private static extern int mixerOpen(
                                        out int phmx,
                                        int uMxId,
                                        int dwCallback,
                                        int dwInstance,
                                        int fdwOpen);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]                                                    // mixerClose
        private static extern int mixerClose(int hmx);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]                                                    // mixerGetControlDetailsA
        private static extern int mixerGetControlDetailsA(
                                            int hmxobj,
                                            ref MIXERCONTROLDETAILS pmxcd,
                                            int fdwDetails);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]                                                    // mixerGetLineControlsA
        private static extern int mixerGetLineControlsA(
                                            int hmxobj,
                                            ref MIXERLINECONTROLS pmxlc,
                                            int fdwControls);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]                                                    // mixerGetLineInfoA
        private static extern int mixerGetLineInfoA(
                                            int hmxobj,
                                            ref MIXERLINE pmxl,
                                            int fdwInfo);

        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]                                                    // mixerSetControlDetails
        private static extern int mixerSetControlDetails(
                                            int hmxobj,
                                            ref MIXERCONTROLDETAILS pmxcd,
                                            int fdwDetails);

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

        public struct MIXERCONTROL                                                                          // MIXERCONTROL
        {
            public int cbStruct;                    // Size in bytes of MIXERCONTROL
            public int dwControlID;                 // Unique control ID for mixer device
            public int dwControlType;               // MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLTYPE_xxx
            public int fdwControl;                  // MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLF_xxx
            public int cMultipleItems;              // If MIXERCONTROL_CONTROLF_MULTIPLE set

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,
            SizeConst = MIXER_SHORT_NAME_CHARS)]
            public string szShortName;              // Short name of control

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,
            SizeConst = MIXER_LONG_NAME_CHARS)]
            public string szName;                   // Long name of control

            public int lMinimum;                    // Minimum value
            public int lMaximum;                    // Maximum value

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4,
            SizeConst = 10)]
            public int reserved;
        }

        public struct MIXERCONTROLDETAILS                                                                   // MIXERCONTROLDETAILS
        {
            public int cbStruct;                    // Size in bytes of MIXERCONTROLDETAILS
            public int dwControlID;                 // Control ID to get/set details on
            public int cChannels;                   // Number of channels in paDetails array
            public int item;                        // hwndOwner or cMultipleItems
            public int cbDetails;                   // Size of _one_details_XX struct
            public IntPtr paDetails;                // Pointer to array of details_XX_struct
        }

        public struct MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED                                                          // MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED
        {
            public int dwValue;
        }

        public struct MIXERLINE                                                                             // MIXERLINE
        {
            public int cbStruct;                    // Size of MIXERLINE struct
            public int dwDestination;               // Zero based destination index
            public int dwSource;                    // Zero based source index (if source)
            public int dwLineID;                    // Unique line ID for mixer device
            public int fdwLine;                     // State/information about line
            public int dwUser;                      // Driver specific information
            public int dwComponentType;             // Component type line connects to
            public int cChannels;                   // Number of channels line supports
            public int cConnections;                // Number of possible connections
            public int cControls;                   // Number of controls belonging to this line

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,
            SizeConst = MIXER_SHORT_NAME_CHARS)]
            public string szShortName;              // Short name of control

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,
            SizeConst = MIXER_LONG_NAME_CHARS)]
            public string szName;                   // Long name of control

            public int dwType;
            public int dwDeviceID;
            public int wMid;                        // Manufacturer ID                        
            public int wPid;                        // Product ID
            public int vDriverVersion;              // Driver Vers. No.

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,
            SizeConst = MAXPNAMELEN)]
            public string szPname;                  // Product name
        }

        public struct MIXERLINECONTROLS                                                                     // MIXERLINECONTROLS
        {
            public int cbStruct;                    // Size in bytes of MIXERLINECONTROLS
            public int dwLineID;                    // Line ID (from MIXERLINE.dwLineID)
            // MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYID or
            public int dwControl;                   // MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE
            public int cControls;                   // Number of controls pamxctrl points to
            public int cbmxctrl;                    // Size in bytes of _one_ MIXERCONTROL
            public IntPtr pamxctrl;                 // Pointer to first MIXERCONTROL array
        }

        // This function attempts to obtain a specified mixer control/component pair - 
        // returns true if successful.
        private static bool GetMixerControl(                                                                // GetMixerControl
                                        int hmixer,
                                        int component,
                                        int control,
                                        out MIXERCONTROL mxc,
                                        out int vCurrentVol)
        {
            bool retValue = false;
            mxc = new MIXERCONTROL();

            MIXERLINECONTROLS mxlc = new MIXERLINECONTROLS();
            MIXERLINE mxl = new MIXERLINE();
            MIXERCONTROLDETAILS pmxcd = new MIXERCONTROLDETAILS();
            MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED du = new MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED();

            vCurrentVol = -1;       // A dummy value

            mxl.cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(mxl);
            mxl.dwComponentType = component;

            int rc = mixerGetLineInfoA(
                                hmixer,
                                ref mxl,
                                MIXER_GETLINEINFOF_COMPONENTTYPE);

            if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR == rc)
            {
                int sizeofMIXERCONTROL = 152;
                int ctrl = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIXERCONTROL));
                mxlc.pamxctrl = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeofMIXERCONTROL);
                mxlc.cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(mxlc);
                mxlc.dwLineID = mxl.dwLineID;
                mxlc.dwControl = control;
                mxlc.cControls = 1;
                mxlc.cbmxctrl = sizeofMIXERCONTROL;

                // Allocate a buffer for the control 
                mxc.cbStruct = sizeofMIXERCONTROL;

                // Get the control 
                rc = mixerGetLineControlsA(
                                        hmixer,
                                        ref mxlc,
                                        MIXER_GETLINECONTROLSF_ONEBYTYPE);

                if (MMSYSERR_NOERROR == rc)
                {
                    retValue = true;
                    // Copy the control into the destination structure 
                    mxc = (MIXERCONTROL)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                                                            mxlc.pamxctrl,
                                                            typeof(MIXERCONTROL));
                }

                int sizeofMIXERCONTROLDETAILS =
                    Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIXERCONTROLDETAILS));

                int sizeofMIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED =
                    Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED));

                pmxcd.cbStruct = sizeofMIXERCONTROLDETAILS;
                pmxcd.dwControlID = mxc.dwControlID;
                pmxcd.paDetails = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeofMIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED);
                pmxcd.cChannels = 1;
                pmxcd.item = 0;
                pmxcd.cbDetails = sizeofMIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED;

                rc = mixerGetControlDetailsA(
                                    hmixer,
                                    ref pmxcd,
                                    MIXER_GETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE);

                du = (MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                                                            pmxcd.paDetails,
                                                            typeof(MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED));

                vCurrentVol = du.dwValue;

                return retValue;    // true
            }

            return retValue;        // false
        }

        private static bool SetVolumeControl(                                                               // SetVolumeControl
                                    int hmixer,
                                    MIXERCONTROL mxc,
                                    int volume)
        {
            bool retValue = false;
            int rc;

            MIXERCONTROLDETAILS mxcd = new MIXERCONTROLDETAILS();
            MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED vol = new MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED();

            mxcd.item = 0;
            mxcd.dwControlID = mxc.dwControlID;
            mxcd.cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(mxcd);
            mxcd.cbDetails = Marshal.SizeOf(vol);

            // Allocate a buffer for the control value buffer 
            mxcd.cChannels = 1;
            vol.dwValue = volume;

            // Copy the data into the control value buffer 
            mxcd.paDetails = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(
                                Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIXERCONTROLDETAILS_UNSIGNED)));

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(
                                vol,
                                mxcd.paDetails,
                                false);

            // Set the control value 
            rc = mixerSetControlDetails(
                                    hmixer,
                                    ref mxcd,
                                    MIXER_SETCONTROLDETAILSF_VALUE);

            return retValue = MMSYSERR_NOERROR == rc ? true : false;
        }

        public static int GetVolume(int control, int component)                                             // GetVolume
        {
            int hmixer = 0;
            int currVol = -1;

            MIXERCONTROL volCtrl = new MIXERCONTROL();

            int rc = mixerOpen(
                            out hmixer,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0);

            bool b = GetMixerControl(
                                hmixer,
                                component,
                                control,
                                out volCtrl,        // Not used
                                out currVol);

            mixerClose(hmixer);

            return currVol;
        }

        public static void SetVolume(int control, int component, int newVol)                              // SetVolume
        {
            int hmixer = 0;
            int currentVol;

            MIXERCONTROL volCtrl = new MIXERCONTROL();

            mixerOpen(
                    out hmixer,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0);

            GetMixerControl(
                        hmixer,
                        component,
                        control,
                        out volCtrl,
                        out currentVol);            // Not used

            SetVolumeControl(hmixer, volCtrl, newVol);

            mixerClose(hmixer);
        }

        public static bool MonitorControl(int iw)     // iw is the window handle                          // MonitorControl
        {
            int rc = -1;
            bool retValue = false;

            int hmixer;
            rc = mixerOpen(
                        out hmixer,
                        0,
                        iw,
                        0,
                        CALLBACK_WINDOW);

            return retValue = (MMSYSERR_NOERROR == rc) ? true : false;
        }

        public static int CheckMixer()                                                                      // CheckMixer
        {
            int retValue = -1;
            int rc1, rc2 = -1;
            int hmixer;

            rc1 = mixerOpen(
                        out hmixer,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0);

            rc2 = mixerClose(hmixer);

            return retValue = (MMSYSERR_NOERROR == rc1) && (MMSYSERR_NOERROR == rc2) ? MMSYSERR_NOERROR : retValue;
        }

        public static int GetControlID(int component, int control)                                        // GetControlID
        {
            MIXERCONTROL mxc = new MIXERCONTROL();
            int _i;         // Though we won't need _i, it still must be declared                                    

            bool b = false;
            int retValue = 0;

            b = GetMixerControl(
                            0,
                            component,
                            control,
                            out mxc,
                            out _i);

            return retValue = b ? mxc.dwControlID : -1;
        }

    }
}
```

if this still doesnt work, try Naudio (https://naudio.codeplex.com/) and call as follows:

```
public void SetVolume(int level)
   {
            try
            {
                //Instantiate an Enumerator to find audio devices
                    NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator MMDE = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator();
                        //Get all the devices, no matter what condition or status
                NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceCollection DevCol = MMDE.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DataFlow.All, NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.All);
                //Loop through all devices
                foreach (NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice dev in DevCol)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (dev.State == NAudio.CoreAudioApi.DeviceState.Active)
                        {
                            var newVolume = (float)Math.Max(Math.Min(level, 100),0) / (float)100;

                            //Set at maximum volume
                            dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = newVolume;

                            dev.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = level == 0;

                            //Get its audio volume
                            _log.Info("Volume of " + dev.FriendlyName + " is " + dev.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar.ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.Debug("Ignoring device " + dev.FriendlyName + " with state " + dev.State);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Do something with exception when an audio endpoint could not be muted
                        _log.Warn(dev.FriendlyName + " could not be muted with error " + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //When something happend that prevent us to iterate through the devices
                _log.Warn("Could not enumerate devices due to an excepion: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what should i pass in place of NULL

Comment: with null it doesn't match with best overload method.

Comment: in setVolume() its giving can not set volume   if (vVolume != currentVol)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot Set Volume");
            }

Comment: hmmmm... what are the values of your vVolume and currentVol? Should be the same, no?

Comment: no vVolume i have given 100 and current vol is 99. But it has not changed volume to 99 also.

Comment: please take a look at my original post. I have changed it and it should work  for you.. Please run the entire code separately in a console project and let me know...