# Programmatically adjust the volume on my Windows 7 computer

Tags: python, windows, volume

I was wondering if it was possible to make a Tkinter scale correspond with the volume of the computer.  In other words, by dragging the scale up, could the volume of the computer increase?  Here is just some random code I drew up.  I am running a a 64-Bit Windows 7 operating system.

```
1    from Tkinter import *
2
3    def sel():
4       selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
5       label.config(text = selection)
6
7    root = Tk()
8    var = DoubleVar()
9    scale = Scale( root, variable = var )
10   scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)
11
12   button = Button(root, text="Get Scale Value", command=sel)
13   button.pack(anchor=CENTER)
14
15   label = Label(root)
16   label.pack()
17
18   root.mainloop()
```

Honestly I do not care if it can't be done.  I was just wondering if it was possible.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It's possible, but the implementation depends entirely on what operating system (or sound system for Linux) you're running.

Comment: 64-Bit Windows 7.  I always forget to add that.

Comment: This question should really be "How do I programmatically adjust the volume on my computer?" It really has nothing to do with `Tkinter`.

Comment: Okay sorry.  I just figured because it used a Tkinter interface.  But I do suppose you are correct.  Do you have an answer though?

Answer (score 1):

See [Changing master volume level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294292/changing-master-volume-level) for how to do this in C and then mix with [How to use win32 API's with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025029/how-to-use-win32-apis-with-python).  Then bind your resulting callbacks to Tkinter gui events.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but the top answer is out of the scope of most people's abilities. I write in python to avoid C, not to embrace it.

The realistic best answer is to install something for the command line (e.g. [Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)) and then to use `subprocess` (preinstalled) to call it e.g.`subprocess.getoutput("nircmd setsysvolume 0")` Hope this helps anyone else who finds it.