# Tkinter: Volume Slider in Windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, windows-8.1

I have been developing a small app to do various different things such as for me opening Steam, Skype and games for steam. Shut down restart and sleep. I am now developing a small volume slider to go with my application at the bottom. But I cannot seem to find anywhere or anything to do to get this to work. For the volume slider I am currently using these lines of code:

```
w = Scale(win, from_=0, to=100, length = 200, tickinterval = 10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w.set(23)
```

Then:

```
w.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

But cannot seem to find a way for this to control my windows volume. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically adjust the volume on my Windows 7 computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769709/programmatically-adjust-the-volume-on-my-windows-7-computer)

Comment: As I was typing in the question nothing related to this appeared. I am just asking a question on how to change my volume on windows 8.1 which is different in ways to windows 7.

Comment: @GhostFrag1 I have added Windows 8.1 tags to the question and updated the title. However, if you still don't get an answer, it may be useful to post a more specific "How to programatically adjust volume in Windows 8.1" type question.

Comment: Have you actually tried the technique suggested in the linked question and had it not work on Windows 8? If so, what exactly doesn't work?